# I need to prevent the fields in my form from automatically appending data to the record

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

So I have a data entry platform that I've basically created in Access. Upon entry, each field will append to the backend table. So if someone types Sally in the First Name field, it'll append each keystroke. I can't have that.

I want to prevent that from happening and instead add a "Save Record" button which appends all of the data in one fell swoop. I'm using a tab control which has two subforms, one for address data and another for misc. data. The main form and these two subforms are all related to the same record.

So having a save record button alongside a refresh fields and next record button are critical.

Comment: Please read about **bound** vs. **unbound** forms.

Comment: Okay awesome. So what I got from that is this --- make the fields unbound, because they're currently bound, then write a macro on the button to append the data to its appropriate field in the table? Is that the most efficient way of doing that?